# Какие языки программирования хороши для создания кросс-платформенных desktop приложений?

Tags: кроссплатформенность, desktop

Смотрел Java. В x64 системе окошко с хелловорлдом отъедает около 20 МБ памяти, и это число быстро растёт при создании новых объектов. Mono - достаточно посмотреть на плеер Banshee чтобы понять что там ситуация не лучше (Музыкальный плеер отъедает ~ 100 МБ памяти, при том что я всегда держу загруженный плеер мне это не нравится).

С++/Qt кажется неплохо, но на изучение придётся потратить большое кол-во усилий, при том что не известно оправдаются ли(Вообще у Qt сейчас как я вижу не самая стабильная ситуация, да и с плюсами в новых проектах люди стали поосторожнее)

Python/PyGTK оказался на удивление более скромным к памяти чем java, но сам язык кажется мне каким-то невменяемым, возможно я просто не понимаю динамичскую типизацию. Отсутствие инкапсуляции и перегрузки функций удивляет. Непонятно какое значение возвращает какая-либо функция. Код показался не читаемым как раз из-за отсутствия скобок. Где-то наткнулся на совет реже использовать вызовы функций, особенно в циклах т.к. это дорогая операция в питоне. Перед глазами сразу представились огромные методы в 200+ строк.

PS Возможно я в чём-то не прав т.к. посмотрел на эти языки весьма поверхностно. Кросс-платформенность на уровне компиляции вполне устроила бы(с неизменным кодом).

Comment: "В x64 системе окошко с хелловорлдом отъедает около 20 МБ памяти, и это число быстро растёт при создании новых объектов. Mono - достаточно посмотреть на плеер Banshee чтобы понять что там ситуация не лучше" - это всё из-за неправильного использования и конфигурирования виртуальных машин.

Comment: Кстати, каким образом вы определили 20М и более? Откуда вообще цифра 20? Если речь о виртуальной памяти, то виртуальная машина на 20 метрах вообще не запустится. Потому что требуется много памяти для отображения динамических нативных библиотек: при этом реальная физическая память не расходуется. PS: у меня на 20 метрах даже vim запуститься не может.

Comment: free - смотрим свободную память без буферов и кэшей, запускаем затем ещё раз free. Почему python ест меньше для меня загадка.

Comment: А как вы думаете, почему на питоне не пишут большие приложения, работающие дольше, чем CGI-скрипт? Представьте себе, что вам пришлось бы писать на нём приложения класса Eclipse или IDEA.. я не сомневаюсь, что будет epic fail.

Comment: Почему будет фейл?

Answer (score 10):

Что лучше зависит от критериев выбора. В данном случае они такие:
Время разработки и время внесения изменений (*причем второе может быть важней первого для заказных приложений*).
Сложность приложения.
Тип приложения(*"фотошоп", "WoW" или "клиент к твиттеру"*), тиражное или заказное.

1. **С++**
   скорость разработки самая низкая

   для сложных приложений

   для тиражных решений требующих высокой оптимизации выполнения. Для слабого железа - GPS навигаторы, банкоматы, станки с ЧПУ, ...
2. **Java**
   время разработки меньше чем у C++. Особенно время внесения изменений, доработок

   для сложных приложений

   когда требуется эффективность выполнения программы (*перерасход памяти беспокоит только молодых программистов. Ни производителей смартфонов на Android, ни заказчиков бизнес софта это свойство JVM не волнуют. И мою жену тоже не волнует сколько отъедает музыкальный плеер*), и при этом не требуется оптимизация выполнения с помощью низкоуровневых трюков или специфики ОС.
3. **Python**
   время разработки самое низкое

   для простой и средней сложности приложений (*для сложных - только при высокой квалификации программистов или формализованного процесса разработки*)

   для некритичных к времени выполнения(*примеры - клиент Dropbox'а, wikidpad*). Для заказных, малотиражных приложений. (*программы на серверах гугла и яндекса - "заказные", потому что уникальны*)

---

О времени разработки молодые программисты обычно не задумываются.
А частенько в жизни - побеждает не лучшее, а - первое. Особенно при работе под заказ.

**О динамической типизации.**
Она требует самодисциплины разработки, чего обычно нет у молодых программистов, и они сами себе "злые буратины" быстро превращающие код в полный хаос.
Она требует обязательного и сурового применения TDD или подобных методик.

Интерпретатор/компилятор ЯП с динамической типизацией никогда не сможет выполнять/генерировать код той же эффективности выполнения что с статической типизацией.

---

К вопросу - нравится/не нравится какой-то язык программирования.

Во-первых, часто "не нравится" это - "не знал, не знаю, и знать не хочу"

Во-вторых, когда после нескольких законченных и работающих программ остается "не нравится" то действительно стоит подумать о смене языка программирования.  Разработка на любимом языке программирования - очень важный мотиватор для уменьшения времени разработки и улучшении ее качества.

(О себе - профессионально(то есть за деньги) писал на plain С, Java, Python)

Comment: единственный достойный внимания ответ посреди изобилия тем для холиваров

Answer (score 4):

Qt сама по себе не так сложна, если знакомы с С++. Зато возможности мощнейшие. Кросплатформенность тотальная! Ценю Qt еще и за то, что компоновка внешнего вида объектов  происходит почти автоматом - не получается аляпистых кривых окон (как это часто любят делать программеры делфи). Для любой ОС внешний вид приложения будет идентичен - можно не опасаясь писать под виндой приложение которое будет потом скомпилировано и под Linux, и оно будет выглядеть одинаково и там и там.
Мощнейший набор классов на все случаи жизни - мультимедиа, графика, текстовые редакторы, базы данных и т.д. 
Стабильность и поддержка очень крупной компанией. Регулярные релизы. 
Наличие свободной версии и версии для мобильных устройств.

Сложность изучения языка и самого набора библиотек окупается многократно.

Answer (score 4):

Отвечу про Python.

> Отсутствие инкапсуляции и перегрузки функций удивляет.

Инкапсуляция в питоне, хоть и весьма условная, но есть. 
Если метод начинается с __, то интерпретатор автоматически добавляет к имени префикс _%current_class% и, соответственно, в другом классе такой метод уже не будет виден. [Private Methods](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

```
"""
>>> obj = bar()
>>> obj.__test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'bar' object has no attribute '__test'

>>> obj.test2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_bar__test'

>>> obj._foo__test()
Hello

>>> obj._foo__test
<bound method bar.__test of <__main__.bar object at 0x...>>
"""

import doctest

class foo():
    def __test(self):
        print('Hello')

class bar(foo):
    def test2(self):
       super().__test()

doctest.testmod(optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

Таким образом достигается инкапсуляция атрибутов класса. Конечно-же, все еще можно обратится к такому методу по полному имени. Однако, для примера, и в C# можно обратиться к приватным методам через рефлексию, но это вовсе не значит, что эти методы публичные.

Для создания абстрактных классов используется специальный [метакласс](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/abc.html?highlight=abcmeta#abc.ABCMeta) c [декораторами](http://docs.python.org/py3k/glossary.html#term-decorator).

```
"""
>>> obj = bar()
>>> obj.test()
Hello

>>> obj = baz()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class baz with abstract methods test
"""

import abc
import doctest

class foo(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        print('Hello')

class bar(foo):
    def test(self):
        super().test()

class baz(foo):
    pass

doctest.testmod()
```

Аналогичным образом реализуются и интерфейсы.

Что-же касается перегрузок функций, то в динамическом языке, где методы могут принимать переменное число параметров и значения по умолчанию - это не возможно, да и совершенно не нужно. Пример:

```
"""
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, arg1=1, arg2=2, bar=False)
(1, 2, (3, 4, 5), False, {'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2})
"""

import doctest

def foo(first, second, *args, bar=True, **kwargs):
    print( (first, second, args, bar, kwargs) )

doctest.testmod()
```

> Непонятно какое значение возвращает какая-либо функция

Да, этот недостаток присущ, наверное, всем динамическим языкам. Однако, в оправдание питона могу сказать, что эта проблема частично решается при помощи [аннотаций](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), полноценного IDE и хорошего документирования функций.

Более того, при помощи аннотаций, метаклассов и декораторов не сложно реализовать и статическую типизацию :) Т.е. примерно следующее:

```
"""
>>> foo().bar([1, 2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: 'param' is 'list', but the expected type is 'int'

>>> foo().bar(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: function return is 'str', but the expected type is 'bool'
"""

class foo(metaclass=StrongTyping):
    def bar(param: int) -> bool:
        return 'some text'
```

Разумеется, что бы пример работал, нужно еще реализовать метакласс StrongTyping.

> Код показался не читаемым как раз из-за отсутствия скобок.

Вероятно, это дело привычки. Отсутствие скобок обязывает программиста следить за отступами и использовать единый символ табуляции, что уже, на мой взгляд, не мало. Что же касается визуального разделения методов, то тут помогаю IDE, которые отделяют их горизонтальными линиями.

> Где-то наткнулся на совет реже использовать вызовы функций, особенно в циклах т.к. это дорогая операция в питоне. Перед глазами сразу представились огромные методы в 200+ строк.

На мой взгляд, гибкость питона и такие возможности, как [генераторы выражений](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/classes.html#generators) наоборот позволяют писать очень компактные и лаконичные конструкции. Там где для строго-типизированных языков требуются куча циклов и условных конструкций, в питоне решается одной строчкой.

UPD. Какие преимущества у динамической типизации? Имхо, именно в динамичности. Где еще можно написать нечто подобное:

```
"""
>>> op = ImportantClass()
>>> op.foo(1)

>>> ImportantClass.debug(True)
>>> op.foo(2)
Called  <function foo at 0x...> (<__main__.ImportantClass object at 0x...>, 2) {} None
"""

import doctest
import functools

def logging(func):
    """ Декоратор функции, который логирует все вызовы """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('Called ', func, args, kwargs, ret)
        return ret

    # одна из особенностей питона - это то, что все является объектами
    # добавляем атрибут к функции
    wrapper.original = func
    return wrapper

def debugging(cls):
    """ Декоратор класса, добавляет метод debug(enable) """

    @classmethod
    def debug(cls, enable=True):
        attr = '__call__' if enable else 'original'
        call = lambda f: logging(f) if enable else f.original

        # в цикле подменяются все функции на logging(f), либо на оригинальные,
        # которые хранятся в декораторе
        for func in [call(f) for f in cls.__dict__.values() if hasattr(f, attr)]:
            setattr(cls, func.__name__, func)

    # добавляем новый метод для декорируемого класс
    # именно для класса, декоратор вызывается только один раз
    cls.debug = debug
    return cls

@debugging
class ImportantClass():

    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass # do something important

    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass # also do something

doctest.testmod(optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

Декораторы logging и debugging можно вынести в отдельный модуль и применять для любых классов. При этом при выключенной отладке накладных расходов практически не будет, т.к. методы именно заменяеются другими методоми, а не оборачиваются.

С другой стороны именно эта динамичность может служить источником ошибок, по этому приходится использовать ее осторожно и не забывать про тестирование.

Кстати,на самом деле считается, что [питон имеет одновременно и строгую, и динамическую типизацию](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language). Т.н. код `"1" + 1` выбросит исключение TypeError.

Comment: Добавлю еще, что для питона есть библиотека PyQt

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ. А какую IDE используете для python лично вы? И какие приятные стороны у динамической типизации? (Если учесть то, что объявлять переменные, и при необходимости приводить типы явно - не проблема)

Comment: Я использую [PyCharm][1] от команды JetBrains. Очень доволен, у этой IDE и автодополнение неплохо работает, и отладчик, и развиватся она очень активно.

Про динамическую типизацию добавил в ответ, сюда не вместилось =)

[1]: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: вы пишите на py3k в PyCharm?

Comment: Да. Но откровенно говоря, в боевых проектах у нас питон используется только в качестве триггеров postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

- Свой сверхвысокоуровневый DSL (Domain Specific Language, заточенный под **ваши** задачи) +
- автогенерация кода для (полусотни) целевых платформ

  - х (PC *2 /win,lin/ *2 (x32,x64), Mac, Android *2 /4.x, backport-затычки 2.x/, iPhone, смарт-часы, облака
  - х количество СУБД/хранилищ данных каждая со своими заморочками
  - х Java, С#, JavaScript и еще десяток ходовых ЯП потому что понадобилась какая-то уникальная библиотека или работа приложения в специфическом окружении, или заказчик ограничил т.к. у него есть спецы для поддержки знающие что-то одно.

По универсальности/эффективности и доступности вотпрямщщас: связка Python и С++, и нативные библиотеки GUI, интерфейса к БД итд, завернутые в классы с одним интерфейсом (для каждого вида -- GUI, БД,..).