# Ruby, Python  - чем так хороши?

Tags: python, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Недавно встечался со с одним директором агенства по сайтам, тот мне сказал учи Питона и Руби, за сайты на этих технологиях в 3 раза больше платят, чем php проггерам, ну я понимаю программистов php во много раз больше чем в вышеприведённых двух языках. Но зачем заказчикам переплачивать за это? На сколько я знаю функционал не особо отличается...
Ну и с чего начать изучать данные языки?)

Comment: Конкретно могут ответить, не беря в счет скорость.
Функции? Что я не смогу сделать на пхп, что сделаю на ruby и python?


Comment: Дело тут не столько в том, "что?", сколько в том "как?" На вскидку - передача функций как параметров, анонимные функции, вложенные классы/функции, замена функций в объекте... Питон и руби - это совершенно другой уровень свободы по сравнению с PHP. Кроме того сайт на питоне/руби - это приложение, а на php это в лучшем случае fastcgi и делать из него приложение по меньшей мере не целесообразно...

Comment: @milan105, а я и на Shell в \*nix (ну, с добавками на C и правами root) могу что угодно сотворить. Вопрос в **модифицируемости** и эффективности этого творения.

Comment: Если вести речь о том, что *в принципе* возможно, то можно сказать, что сотворить всё что угодно можно на **любом** полным по Тьюрингу языке ) (например, написать интерпретатор питона/руби на php или наоборот).

Comment: Или написать на Python'е [JIT-компилятор для brainfuck](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/124418/) или [Interactive shell for php](http://www.phpsh.org/)  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не вижу причин, почему бы благородным донам не похоливарить? :)

Впрочем, чего впустую воздух гонять. [Основные "за" и "против" уже давно расписаны](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsPhp), выделю только ключевые, на мой взгляд, моменты:

- Веб приложения на Python (а также на Ruby, Java, C#, etc) - это все, в отличии от PHP, "true runtime" приложения. Т.е. среда выполнения на этих языках инициализируется один единственный раз при запуске воркера(сервера), в то время когда в PHP эта инициализация происходит при *каждом* запросе.
- Python потрясающе гибкий язык. Для примера, посмотрите [последний листинг моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/14571/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-desktop-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=14599#14599) с включением логирования вызовов. Попробуйте сделать тоже самое на PHP ? :)
- Множественное наследование. Посмотрите как в Yii извращаются с [Behavior](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.9/framework/base/CComponent.php), что бы достичь похожего функционала.
- И для кучи: генераторы, декораторы, метаклассы, тесная интеграция с C, etc. Все расписывать не вижу смысла.

Answer (score 10):

Ну вы знаете, один мой друг долгое время утверждал что опель это офигенные машины. Потом попробовал другие, и начал понимать разницу.Возьмите и напишите сайт на одном и другом, потом сравните свои ощущения. Вы поймите правильно, большинство из суждений прочитанных вами тут субъективны. Не стоит на это обращать внимание. Все хвалят свое болото, берите пиво, сходите в гости к тем и другим. Где понравится там и квакайте. Я уже знаете сколько таких тем видел? Все закончились холливаром, и эта закончится, и вы таких тем еще 1000 потому сами увидете. И так пока нас всех не накроет комета. Аминь.

Answer (score 4):

Например Python изобретал ученый, а не школьник (как в случае с пхп). Для некоторых это является весомым аргументом. А различие в скорости разработки и удобстве.

Те, если будет необходимость создать сайт, который не похож на существующие (не шаблонный), тут как никак скорость разработки играет решающую роль.

Comment: А как это не шаблонный сайт? Можно пример?

Comment: Что касается не шаблонных сайтов ИМХО гораздо большее значение имеет клиент чем сервер

[offtop]Лично меня **убивает** синтаксис питона =\[offtop]

Comment: шаблон != вёрстка. Шаблон это блог, интернет-магазин, форум. Не шаблонный это стартапы предлагающие новые сервисы, которые пишутся не на CMS, а на фреймфворках, так вот все эти Yii и симфонии - это жалкая потуга сделать из PHP что-то порядочное. Хотя, конечно, я так не думал, пока писал на PHP...

А по поводу-синтаксиса питона... Ну, я могу только посочувствовать...

Comment: Фигурные скобочки к питону добавить и все ОК.

Comment: Без них гораздо проще рефакторить, хотя я сначала думал что без них будет непонятно где конец, но оказалось, что это надумано и на практике они никуда не упёрлись...

Comment: Отсутствие фигурных скобок заставляет программиста, хоть и отчасти, следовать единому стилю.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что PHP никто толком не проектировал, просто лепили всё в кучу не особенно задумываясь о консистентности. ООП прилепили совершенно сбоку. В последних версиях пытаются что-то исправить, но зачем, когда есть уже более-менее "правильные" языки одной весовой категории: Ruby, Python.

Вот, к примеру [подборка цитат](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf) создателя PHP.
Вот к примеру хорошая цитата иллюстрирующая его отношение к языку:

> I'm not a real programmer. I throw together things until it works then I move on. The real programmers will say "Yeah it works but you're leaking memory everywhere. Perhaps we should fix that." I’ll just restart Apache every 10 requests.

Или ещё откровеннее:

> I don't know how to stop it, there was never any intent to write a programming language [...] I have absolutely no idea how to write a programming language, I just kept adding the next logical step on the way.

Если необходимо сделать что-то достаточно сложное, что будет часто меняться и будет иметь нетривиальную архитектуру, то PHP здесь неудобен.

Comment: Хотя я и согласен - это никак не раскрывает прелесть руби и пайтона.

И не смотря на то что я согласен - скажите это facebook'у. Все зависит от рук а не от языка.

Comment: facebook, в лице самого Цукерберга комментировали это, и объясняли что так сложилось исторически. Если вы не в курсе, те весь facebook уже давно откомпилен, все что связывает facebook с php это синтаксис, не более.

Comment: > никак не раскрывает прелесть руби и пайтона.

У питона с руби хотя бы нет проблем с областью видимости, глобальными переменными. Там хотя бы есть модульность. Это чертовски важно для крупных проектов. Ну и они гораздо гибче.

> И не смотря на то что я согласен - скажите это facebook'у. Все зависит от рук а не от языка.

А зачем facebook'у что-то менять, когда всё и так уже работает? Переобучать персонал, перестраивать сервера?

От рук бесспорно зависит. От инструмента тоже.

Comment: Так вот и я об этом - facebook живет и процветает, один из самых крупных веб-гигантов, написан на PHP.
(не подумайте неправильно - не являюсь религиозным поклонником секты ПыХаПы)

"нет проблем с областью видимости, глобальными переменными"???

Мы рассматриваем школьника бидлокодера что-ли? LOL

Comment: раскройте мысль.

Comment: Vladimir VG, а что тут раскрывать? Холиварная тема. Руби ,питон, пхп ,все нашли свою нишу. И рассказывать нужно не facebook а глобально миру. mysql тоже не лутшей в мире, и пофиг. А если копнуть глубже то TCP протокол полный отстой, были лутше. Его долепили, сделали TCPIP . Вот так и живем. Вам еще про ftp рассказать? Ниче ,пользуемся.

Comment: Проблемы глобальной области видимости и глобальных переменных решаются еще на этапе проектирования и не требуют каких-то фантастических познаний и усилий.

Вот теперь раскройте мысль вы "они гораздо гибче", именно это, как мне кажется, наиболее важная делать в контексте этого вопроса но он так и не раскрыта.

Comment: ассемблер всему голова

Comment: ftp - от лукавого! :D

Comment: mikillskegg, достойный финалити для подобных холиваров )))

Comment: В чем выражается холивар? Мне действительно интересно что мне может предложить ruby или python, ответа так и не увидел. Судя по всему так и не увижу

Comment: С таким подходом - точно не увидите. Когда цель топика "убедите меня" то это просто троллинг. Если бы целью было действительно познание, то после пары комментариев Вы бы поставили себе один из языков и попробовали то, о чём пишут другие на деле. Т.к. никто Вас не убедит эмпирически, если Вы не проверите каково это на практике и где может пригодиться, а потом попытались бы повторить тоже самое на PHP. А так - всё пустой трёп...

Comment: Вообще-то я их уже ставил и пробовал, не вдохновило.

В том то и дело что все пишут ниочем, в том числе и вы. 

PS:ваш коммент не пустой треп?

Comment: @Arni: "А если копнуть глубже то TCP протокол полный отстой, были лутше. Его долепили, сделали TCPIP ." -- шедевр. "Ассемблер -- всему голова" -- бледнеет на фоне этого шедевра.

Comment: > Вообще-то я их уже ставил и пробовал, не вдохновило.

ниасилил?

Comment: написал-же - не вдохновило(те же яйца только сбоку), соответственно и асиливать не вижу смысла

Answer (score 2):

ruby и python изначально проектировались для поддержки современных парадигм и паттернов программирования. Кроме того, это полноценные языки программирования в которых добавлено многое, что из них переняли более молодые языки. Ну а PHP - он как был Personal Home Page так и остался. Он конечно вырос, но и остальные на месте не стоят. Программистов на нём много потому что в нём всё решается кувалдой, там особо думать не надо. Сам долго писал на PHP и думал что больше ничего не нужно - его достаточно, но когда перешёл на python понял как разнообразен и красочен этот мир, а не только серые оттенки PHP.

Начать рекомендую с сайтов языков, там всегда есть ссылки "Для начинающих".

Answer (score -1):

Из всех ответов я так и не нашел, толкового ответа на вопрос ТС.
Каждый может говорить что вон какой то там PHP слеплен из чего то, он вобше за язык не считается, на нем делают не сайты а не знае что. Реальные примеры ни кто не дал, он инструмент и он не виноват что дает свободу и не заганяет вас в рамки, хотя это и его большой минус. Вы же не говорите резак для дерева это что то слепленое из чегото, изобрели древние люди и он бесполезный если у вас получаются кривые обрубки? PHP хороший инструмент для своих целей, ненадо его винить в том что люди делают на нем.

Comment: php это инструмент без сомнения, но питон или руби инструмент во много раз лучший и требующий меньше усилий для достижения аналогичного результата. всё равно что вырубить Давида из мрамора куском камня или дать 3D модель роботу который вырежет его лазером с точностью до микрона.

Comment: Вы не задавались вопросом тогда почему 90% сайтов работают на PHP?
Можете только - в карму ставить, опровергнуть свою сторону фактами, ни кто не может, учите руби и питон у меня будет больше работы на пхп, хотя ее и так хоть отбавляй =) Не судите за чужое мнение не судимы будети, я хорошо отношусь к руби и питону хорошие языки, но пхп мне удобние и нравится больше.

Comment: Не задвался, потому, что я работал на PHP достаточно времени чтобы с точно знать почему 90% сайтов работают на PHP. Но можно вспомнить классический закон 20/80 - 20% сайтов в интернете дают 80% трафика. Вы не задавались вопросом почему они написаны не на PHP?

А минус - за ответ не в тему...